# Hbase batch get stuck in waitUntilDone AsyncProcess.java

Tags: java, hbase, hbase-client

I am using HBase client Hbase client 1.4.13 (the issue was there in 1.4.10 as well). One host randomly starts misbehaving and does not return data from hbase. I took the thread dump and many threads are stuck in

```
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$AsyncRequestFutureImpl.waitUntilDone(AsyncProcess.java:1767)
- locked <0x000000043b004280> (a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$AsyncRequestFutureImpl.waitUntilDone(AsyncProcess.java:1733)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.batch(HTable.java:906)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.existsAll(HTable.java:1440)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I check connection stats using netstat, all the hbase connections were in ESTABLISHED state. The source code is available [here](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/rel/1.4.13/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/AsyncProcess.java). Hbase server is 2.X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we were not setting HBASE_CLIENT_IPC_POOL_SIZE, by default it was 1.

After setting it to 3, we did not see the issue anymore.